# Showing a tooltip for a value in a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a GridView in my ASP.Net application, for a column called "Has Holidays". The GridView holds a list of people working on a project. The column basically indicates if the user has any holiday in a selected period. "Yes" if he does, and "No" if he doesn't. Because of screen size, I can't show the dates of his leave. My idea is to allow the user to move a mouse over the cell, and if it's a 'Yes', display a tooltip popup box that shows something like:

Leave:
From 1st March to 15th March
From 19th April to 23rd April

Maybe in a table, nicely formatted. Is there any control that I can use to do this, or is there some special css magic? I am using Ajax Control Toolkit at the moment, but can't see anything there that might help.

Comment: http://www.programming-free.com/2012/12/aspnet-trim-text-with-ellipsis-and-show.html#.Ug8lZayKKDw check this link

Answer (score 2):

HTML allows the 'title' attribute for showing browser-based popups, which look like Windows app tooltips.  Hover over the element to see the text.

```
<span title="Leave: from 1st march to 15th March">No</span>
```

If you want more control, you can look into using jQuery or the AJAXControlToolkit for web forms.

Comment: I have the AJAXControlToolkit - but can't see a control that would handle Hover over type events.

Comment: Use a `HoverMenuExtender` in conjunction with a styled `Panel` control to create a stylized pop-up hover.  It's similar to the method above, but it lets you control the styling.  http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/HoverMenu/HoverMenu.aspx

Answer (score 0):

try ajax toggle button :
for sample coding

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="ChkStatus" runat="server" 
                      oncheckedchanged="ChkStatus_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack ="true"/> <br />
                  <asp:ToggleButtonExtender ID="ChkStatus_ToggleButtonExtender" runat="server" 
                      Enabled="True" TargetControlID="ChkStatus"  ImageWidth="20"
                ImageHeight="20"
                UncheckedImageUrl="~/img/cancel.png"
                CheckedImageUrl="~/img/checked.png"
                CheckedImageAlternateText="Check"
                UncheckedImageAlternateText="UnCheck">
                  </asp:ToggleButtonExtender>
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this by adding tool tip property

' ToolTip ='<%# Bind("Leavedetails") %>'>

More examples refer

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2013/05/jquery-show-gridview-row-details-in.html

http://forums.asp.net/t/1808318.aspx/1